# Automatically add a prefix or suffix onto all columns after a JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql, join, prefix, suffix

I have a sql query that joins 2 tables on the column `product_id`. Pretty straight forward. Result is below:

[image]

However, after joining, I realized I have to do a subquery with all the columns listed here. I obviously need to remove or alias one of the `product_id` columns to prevent ambiguity. Since this is a small table, its not that bad in terms of efficiency to just `SELECT` the relevant columns (7 total). However, this led to me wondering, what if I had 2 giant production-level tables with 100 columns each? It would be incredibly inefficient to type out and `SELECT` 199 columns.

So, thats a long winded way of asking: Is there a way to add a prefix or a suffix to the joined table automatically when joining it (eg. it would say `table2_product_id`)? Or is there a faster way I am unaware of?

Edit: Theres actually 2 `customer_id's` too which further supports my question.

Comment: The 2nd link is helpful but does not answer how to prefix all columns automatically once joined as `table2_col1`, `table2_col2` if you shouldn't use SELECT *?

Comment: The 1st link sadly does not answer it either.

Comment: there is no "automatic" (at least without dynamic sql).  select only the columns you actually want, and alias them appropriately.

Comment: worth noting that if you `inner join b using (product_id)` instead of `inner join b on b.product_id=a.product_id`, you will only get one product_id column from `select *` (but still, don't do `select *`)

Comment: @ysth thank you. i wonder how people that do sql in production overcome this hurdle if they actually need to select 100+ relevant rows

Comment: If you are only selecting the columns you actually need, there is little extra difficulty in adding aliases

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the comments, there is no automatic. there's a function you can add to your query to do it.

you can use a `concat("str", "suffix")` or even `concat("prefix_", "str", "_suffix")`  and you the `as` to alias your column name for the result

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT('prefix_', t1.column1) AS column1,
    CONCAT(t1.column2, '_suffix') AS column2,
    CONCAT('prefix_', t2.column3, '_suffix') AS column3
```

Comment: you can't use an expression as an alias, only an identifier or string

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this means if you had 100 columns you would be typing `CONCAT('prefix_', column_n)` 100 times